# If A and B are independent events, they are mutually exclusive(proof for why its wrong)

Tags: probability

I would like to know if the following proof implies that if A and B are independent, that does not mean that they are mutually exclusive:

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive then $A \cap B$ = $\emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ P($A \cap B$)=0

We know that P($A|B$)=P($A \cap B$)/P($B$), and since $A$ and $B$ are independent, P($A$)=P($A \cap B$)/P($B$) and P($B$) =P($A \cap B$)/P($A$).

Since P($A \cap B$)=0, we immediately obtain that P($A$)=P($B$)=$\frac{0}{\:0}$. Seeing that that is impossible, we must derive that If $A$ and $B$ are independant, they must never be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Think about the idea rather than the formula. When $A$ and $B$ are independent, knowing $A$ happened tells you nothing about $B$. Is that the case when they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If they are mutually exclusive, it means that they cannot happen at the same time, because P($A \cap B$)=0. Since A has nothing to do with B(because they are independent events), they can happen at the same time, therefore they cannot be mutually exclusive. Is that better ? @EthanBolker

Comment: Actually, if one of them is probability 0, then they are guaranteed independent.

Comment: yeah, but that does not solve my question xd @NoLongerBreathedIn

Comment: Now you're close. If they are mutually exclusive then when $A$ happens you know $B$ can't. So knowing about $A$ tells you (a lot) about $B$, so $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is basically it.

- By definition: Independence of events $A, B$ means that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)$
- By definition: Mutual exclusion of events $A,B$ means that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and thus implies that $\mathsf P(A\cap B)= 0$.

So if neither event has a probability measure of $0$, therefore they *cannot* be both independent and mutually exclusive.

Note: If one of the sets does have a probability measure of $0$, then they *will* be independent, and *might* be mutually exclusive.